# Please clarify what is meant by "arbitrarily large"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My classmate and I are debating about a logic exercise. The exercise goes like this:

Let $T$ be an incomplete countable theory. Prove or disprove: If $T$ has finite models and a denumerable model, then $T$ has arbitrarily large finite models.

My friend thinks that a theory with the sentence $\exists x, y (x\ne y)$ should be a counterexample, as it has a finite model (of say size two), a denumerable model, but no "arbitrarily finite model" since he considers $1$ to be arbitrarily large, and there is no model of cardinality $1$ that models his theory. I disagree since I think that it is not enough that he chooses some number and says it is arbitrarily large; I think that for a given arbitarily large number, his theory should not have that model, if his theory is to suffice as a counterexample. Can someone clarify why and how either of us is wrong?

Note that I do not need help with the problem itself (already solved it my way), just to settle this discussion.

Comment: I normally take the statement "there are arbitrarily large finite $x$ such that $P(x)$" to mean "for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists an $x$ with cardinality $>k$ such that $P(x)$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say that a theory has arbitrarily large finite models if for every integer $M$, there is an integer $n\gt M$ such that the theory has a model whose underlying set has size $n$.

Comment: That settles it, thanks.